# TFS 2010 : Unable to add Project to a collection

Tags: visual-studio-2008

This morning I'm trying to setup Team Foundation Server 2010 to demo for my team. As this is just a demo, I thought I would install it on my Windows 7 machine which also serves as my development machine.

My development machine uses Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite. I installed Team Explorer 2008 and then reapplied SP1.

Finally I installed and setup TFS 2010. TFS by default gave me administrator privileges.

I started up Visual Studios, and connected up to the Collection just fine. However, I'm unable to create a new project and get the follow error message:

"TF30172: You are trying to create a team project either without required permissions or with an older version of team Explorer. Contact your project admin..."

To check to permissions, I used my home computer which is running Visual Studio 2010. On this machine I was able to connect up to the same TFS instance and create a project no problem. So it looks as though it is a team explorer problem, but everywhere on the web people are saying not only am what I'm trying to do possible, but they have done it themselves.

What am I missing to add a project to TFS 2010 under Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, creating projects is not supported in 2008. You have to use Team Explorer 2010 in VS2010 to create the project.

Once created, I do believe everything else works fine.